# The count of flagged posts seem decreased

Tags: support, 10k-tools, flags

On english.stackexchange.com, I have access to the moderation tools, and I have noticed that the number of flagged posts was first 5, and now it's 4.

How is this possible? As far I can see, it's only possible to flag a post, not to remove the flag added to a post.

[image: Moderation Tools]

I tried selecting *30d*, *14d*, *7d*, but the result is always the same. To notice that the last time I checked was yesterday, or maybe two days ago.
EDIT: The flagged posts were two, and they are still two now that the flag counter is decreased.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To sum up the [other](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62390/the-count-of-flagged-posts-seem-decreased/62392#62392) [three](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62390/the-count-of-flagged-posts-seem-decreased/62391#62391) [answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62390/the-count-of-flagged-posts-seem-decreased/62394#62394)

Flags can disappear in five ways.

- After two days, a flag will "age away" and disappear.
- If a post reaches the [flag threshold](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22174/how-does-the-offensive-flag-work) (6), the post will be removed from the system. The flags will disappear from your view.
- Rolling back a post will clear any [offensive flags it gained](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18874/what-does-rollback-do-to-a-question/18876#18876) for that revision.
- Moderators can clear flags.
- If a post is deleted by the community or OP, its flags will not show up in the 10k flags view.

Answer (score 6):

To add on the [other](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62390/the-count-of-flagged-posts-seem-decreased/62392#62392) [answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62390/the-count-of-flagged-posts-seem-decreased/62391#62391), diamonds actually *can* clear flags.

Also, a post that gets rolled back will [clear offensive flags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18874/what-does-rollback-do-to-a-question/18876#18876).

I can't flag my own post as offensive or spam. But I do need at least one revision to actual roll back from!

And on a completely unrelated and spammy note, people should play [MMT](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mmt). It is an excellent game and you can pick up a free demo version from the site linked in that wiki!

Comment: [Thank you](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62375/show-a-tooltip-warning-when-an-answers-states-above-or-below/62382#62382) :)

Comment: @Tobias I did seriously consider using "above" just to see how you'd react. ♪

Comment: @GraceNote :p since all three answers are correct, it would be fair if all were +1ed by everyone voting at all thus keeping the order...

Comment: I'm not actually sure rollbacks clear offensive flags anymore. Care to try it out, Grace Note and @Tobias Kienzler? I think an offensive flag from me would destroy the post immediately.

Comment: There, now someone can flag me for offensively saying "actual" instead of "actually". Ima wait for a Spam flag, that way I can see if it applies to only offensive, both, or neither.

Comment: The flag appears in the view. wait five minutes, then roll back.

Comment: @mmyers♦: flagged. I'm insulted by "revision" :p

Comment: @devinb I will be sad if I manage to get 5 offensive before I get a spam.

Comment: funny, I flagged offensive, and now when I try to flag as spam the error still reads "you can only *spam* flag this post once" [bug reported](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62399/trying-to-flag-a-post-as-spam-after-having-it-flagged-offensive-yields-the-wrong)

Comment: @Tobias The two are basically equivalent, since if the sum of both is 6 then the result is the same. The only difference is that spam flags might be used to help construct proactive defense measures in the future.

Comment: @Grace Note: Than we better don't trigger your account to be treated as potential spammer :7

Comment: Successfully spam flagged. @mmyers

Comment: Okay, 2 - 2. Heaven or hell, let's rock! ; That didn't seem to actually do anything.

Comment: Offensive flags cleared. Spam flags are not.

Comment: Can you do me a solid and temporarily delete this post? See if the flags disappear?

Comment: @devinb They're cleared from the system... sorta. But my post score hasn't updated yet. Deletion didn't help. Wonder how long that'll take. But yeah, it is offensive only, not spam.

Comment: Deleting the post didn't clear the flags from the 10k view?

Comment: Oh ye gahds, the score updated but I still have the full penalty despite the wargh and the clearing! Well, I suppose the score will update when the flags age away. @devinb It cleared it from 10k view, but the split-vote-count still says -4; as does my rep report, actually!

Comment: Shall I clear the flags now then?

Comment: Why the -4? one per flag?

Comment: But interestingly, I would've caused one of those downvotes, but my rep didn't go down **and** I was able to upvote you.

Comment: @Tobias Yes, a flag produces a temporary -1. It's counted as a downvote from the Community User. The -1 will go away unless 6 are accumulated and the post gets deleted as flagged, in which case they become permanent.

Comment: @devinb: why would a spam flag induced down-vote (did that actually happen?) cost rep?

Comment: @devinb Flagging has always been separate from voting. It is unfortunate that there are people who basically use it as a "free downvote", which you probably have seen and written answers about on Meta.

Comment: @mmyers Go ahead. We have our research and it is completed.

Comment: @Grace My memory is like a goldfish. I write long posts because I can't keep that volume of information at hand long enough to make it coherently concise. Also, you're bound to get some sympathy upvotes :)

Comment: @Grace: only spam flags or also offensive? And I sincerely hope, mod-attention doesn't cause a down-vote...

Comment: @Tobias Both flag types impose a -1. Mod attention does not.

Comment: Manually clearing the flags seems to also reset the vote counts to the correct numbers.

Answer (score 5):

Did you read this on the right?

> Flags will automatically and harmlessly age away after 2 days if they fail to reach the threshold in that time.

Comment: I read it, but I misunderstood what it meant. As the flags count is now 3, I would think this the reason why it is decreasing.

Answer (score 5):

If enough users have flagged a post it will get removed (quote from SO):

> If any post reaches 6 flags, it is automatically removed from the system.

This will also remove it from the moderation tools.

Comment: This wouldn't make it decrease by one, it would decrease by 6

Comment: @Juan depends on the last time he looked at it. If a post with 1 flag got flagged into removal while he wasn't looking, it would *appear* to go down by just one.

Comment: I forgot to say that the flagged posts were two when the count shown 5 flags, and they were still 2 when the flags count shown 4.