# Where did my downvote go?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, specific-question, down-votes

A question out of mild curiosity because I've never seen this. I got a downvote on [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73939/phpkode-com-links-spamming-stack-overflow).

Vote count: [image]

However, it doesn't show up in my stats, neither for today: 
[image]

Nor yesterday: 
[image]

It is also not in my rep-report.

But the question is a non-CW one, and mine.

How can this be?

Comment: Way to take ownership of that downvote, bud.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a downvote. It's an offensive flag (perhaps for irony?).

The ephemeral state of flags may be responsible for it not showing up in your audit - until it is solidified, it will fade away in about 37 hours. From my experience [over here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62390/the-count-of-flagged-posts-seem-decreased/62394#62394), I saw spam flags in my reputation audit. Offensive may be slightly different in that regard.

There's also the fact there's a delay between when it counts as a downvote and when it is first cast... though I don't think that's responsible for this right now.

Comment: Aaaah! That makes sense, didn't know that. It was most likely flagged for the language. All sorted then, thanks

Comment: @Pekka Oh, hey, yeah, that is some strong language. I can actually understand that flag then.

Comment: yeah, it's all right. The language best reflected my sentiments towards this disgusting practice, but if anybody wants to edit it out, I have no problem with that either