# Make it impossible to put "question" in the title of a question

Tags: feature-request, asking-questions, users

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5978708/c-programming-question
- [Rails Routes Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014095/rails-routes-question)
- [beginner question about python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5094793/beginner-question-about-python)

These are all real "questions" that I've seen on Stack Overflow, and I think that it is completely absurd for someone to be able to post a question on here with "question" in the title. There are several reasons for this:

- OFC it's a question. That's redundant.
- It shows that the OP obviously doesn't care enough about the question to describe it properly.
- It breaks the system that we have in place that keeps duplicate questions from showing up; by not requiring the OP to properly summarize his question in the title, the system is not able to search the title for keywords and suggest questions that have already been asked and answered.

Just my $0.02, and I really hope this isn't a duplicate. I don't spend enough time on Meta to know what questions come and go, and there are a few different ways of asking this, I'm sure.

EDIT: Maybe I should have mentioned that it would be good simply to *notify* the user if he was entering a somewhat unspecific title. Also, thank you @kiamlaluno for the edit.

Comment: Would you want to exclude meta? Because otherwise you won't be able to ask for it like this.

Comment: @Juan Manuel Ha, ha. You could say that if I'd titled this "Question question".

Answer (score 14, accepted):

On the one hand, it's certainly a prevalent problem, nondescriptive titles like that.

On the other hand, I've always been very unfond of [simple string token](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53864/this-is-not-a-forum-notification-if-low-rep-answer-contains-questionmarks) [checks for this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62136/suggestion-for-question-tagged-performance-et-al). We obviously would not impose this on Meta sites, but there are some Q&A sites which may have to run into this.

For theoretical examples of questions involving questions:

- "How do I defeat the Great Question?" (Gaming)
- "Should I discourage asking too many questions?" (Parenting)

For actual examples of questions about questions:

- [Good (preferably free) resource for CISSP practice questions](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/1883/good-preferably-free-resource-for-cissp-practice-questions)
- [How Yes or No Questions Should be Represented in Forms](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/3335/how-yes-or-no-questions-should-be-represented-in-forms)
- [Visiting Apple, what questions should I ask?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/6450/visiting-apple-what-questions-should-i-ask)
- [Questions containing "or"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1888/questions-containing-or)
- ["How to [...]?" and "Where to [...]?" Questions that are not questions. Is this defensible?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/14396/how-to-and-where-to-questions-that-are-not-questions-is-this-d)

It's the kind of thing that would be nice if it could functionally work, but as long as questions are a valid subject matter, it's not something that will be a very wise thing to simple put policy on.

Comment: Very true, I hadn't considered that; maybe a system could be implemented such that a user is notified if his question seems to be of the form, "[Topic] Question".

Comment: @kivetros You might want to figure out what that system looks like, and make sure it works properly, and then propose such a system.

Comment: Very well then. Thank you for your feedback. I half-expected to get 4 close votes and 6 "duplication of" comments, to be honest... I'm surprised that nobody has addressed this before.

Comment: and “How to handle the special case of the question mark character in […]”?